# rsync server and client issue

Tags: rsync

I just configured an rsync server that is hosting the files I would like to replicate to a remote machine. Here is the rsyncd.conf file:

```
max connections = 2
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
timeout = 300

[share]
comment = share
path = /mnt/share
read only = no
list = yes
uid = root
gid = root
auth users = rsync
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

I create a rsyncd.secrets file which looks like:

```
rsync:password
```

After I start the rsync daemon, I issue the following on the remote machine and I see the module

```
[remoteserver] # rsync  rsync://10.0.0.10
share  share
```

With the following setup, what command do I need to issue on the remote server (or the rsync server?) to sync "share" to the local "/tmp/share" for example.

Would it be something like this?

```
rsync -rv rsync://rsync@10.0.0.10::share /tmp/share
```

Comment: Answered your own question. The syntax of your rsync example is correct for pulling the data from the server and placing it in /tmp/share on the client.

Comment: @Tim: when i try that i actually get an error: ssh could not resolve hostname rsync

Comment: Don't know how I missed it, drop the `rsync://rsync@` part. Should just be `rsync -rv 10.0.0.10::share /tmp/share`

Comment: @Tim: Thanks. Now I'm getting another error. auth failed on module share. Do I need to specify the password somewhere? I am not getting a prompt to enter a password on the client where I execute the command.

Comment: Does your password file have the correct permissions? Should be 0600 and owned by root.

Comment: @Tim: It had those permissions but still doesn't work. I managed to get it working by commenting the auth users and secret file options. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is nearly correct, the format of the rsync server URL should be like `host_or_ip::share_name`.